# Manual 301 redirects in OpenCart

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I've changed a few URLs on my OpenCart (version 1.5.6) website and then I've changed them one more time; Google started alerting me that there are dead links and now I'm trying fix things up by adding manual 301 redirects in `.htaccess`: I used to do this whenever I was using WordPress.

I'm more than okay to do each link manually, I actually do prefer this method.

However, whenever I add a line in `.htaccess` it tends to be ignored.

Below is the content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files *.ini>
Order deny,allow
Deny from All
</Files>

SetEnv PHPRC /home/shopurl/
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shopurl.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.shopurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent
</ifModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|xml|json|txt|pdf|mov|avi|otf|woff|ico|swf)$">
    RequestHeader unset Cookie
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
    ErrorDocument 404 'Not Found'
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I achieve that successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all your RewriteRules just after your `RewriteBase /` line, like this:

```
...
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^your-url$ /your-new-url [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^your-page$ /your-new-page [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^your-category$ /your-new-category [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^your-product$ /your-new-product [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
...
```

So it rewrites:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/your-url
- to -
http://www.yoursite.com/your-new-url
```

etc...

Comment: mate, thanks for your help. It works, kinda.. Saying kinda because I have something like 
`RewriteRule ^main-category /main-new-category [R=301,L]` (which works fine)
but I also got something like:
`RewriteRule ^main-category/sub-cat /main-new-category/sub-new-cat [R=301,L]` (which doesn't work...)

Comment: You should have used: `RewriteRule ^main-category$ /main-new-category [R=301,L]` and `RewriteRule ^main-category/sub-cat$ /main-new-category/sub-new-cat [R=301,L]`. Please note the dollar sign after the first parameter of the RewriteRule.

Comment: I would also suggest you to add a version with a slash and a match-all at the end, if you want to rewrite all the products in that category. For example: `RewriteRule ^main-category/(.*)$ /main-new-category/$1 [R=301,L]`